# AngularJs: Loop by class and set model values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Maybe I'm just not thinking this through/researching it correctly, but what I want to do is take a host of DOM elements by class and set their `ng-model` values.

In pseudo code:

```
For x in elements having class foo:
    x.modelValue = 1
```

Comment: Can you go into more detail?  Why do you want to use the class of an element to drive the model?  It sounds like you want an attribute on an element to **direct** what should be happening, in which case that's what a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) is for.  I think a more concrete example could help.

Comment: As the deleted answer by @yusif say: _"What you are doing doesn't sound like the Angular way. Could you elaborate on the reason you're trying to do this?"_ - And I agree 100% with that statement. Please show us your code and describe your issue in more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I do recommend you to rethink your architecture. Because it is better to make view (ie DOM) dependend on your model values not the other way around.

But if you have to go this way for some reason you could do the following

1. Create a directive with the name of your class
2. Limit it's usage to classnames only.
3. Make it to set value in link function.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Uo7y7nCA4CLxfY53Yvuf?p=preview)

```
  .directive('foo', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function(scope, el, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        if(modelCtrl) {
          modelCtrl.$setViewValue('foo')
          modelCtrl.$render()
        }
      }
    }
  })
```